# Chrome Extension: Permissions to manipulate content of data URIs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that needs to inject scripts into data:-URI pages.

When trying to execute the javascript I get an exception:

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "data:text/html;charset=utf-8, … ". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

But which permission would work for me? I tried `data:*`, `<all_urls>`, `*://*/*` - none of these worked. Also the `activeTab` permission did not do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome.tabs.executeScript into dataURI tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051387/chrome-tabs-executescript-into-datauri-tab)

Comment: Someone here claimed it's possible for FF: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/-CfZ-wO0Wsw . Fking Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently [a chromium bug](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/919984) that extensions cannot work on data URIs. A fix is going in that will rectify this, hopefully landing in Chrome 66.

Comment: Any news? A year has passed since the patch has been merged to master and Chrome is 73 now. Still no luck for me.