# chrome.tabs.executeScript into dataURI tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, data-uri-scheme

Question is very simple (to ask)
Is there any way to inject script into tab containing only image
and have URL in form of:
*data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....*

console gives me error:
**Cannot access contents of url "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....**

Comment: No you cannot, but since `data:`-URIs are generally static, you could replace the data URI with another data:-URI or extension page plus your desired functionality.

Comment: @RobW yea, I have extension page, but I wanted to have, sort of speaking "loose end" not hooked to extension views in any form and to keep my BG page asleep. If I open it with dedicated HTML file, and deal with heavy data (image dataURIs) it consumes memory a lot. It looks much nicer to have styled HTML preview, and I was thinking to inject that part independently. I'll try nesting dataURIs (code +image data) somehow

Comment: @RobW, It could be data:text/html too. Chrome should allow us to access it.

Comment: Hooking  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15461142/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37093152/632951

Comment: @Pacerier Note that the folks at Chromium are receptive to supporting content scripts in data:-URLs, it's just that nobody is working on implementing it, see comments 24 - 27 at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55084#c24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is "no". `data:` URIs [are not supported by permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Even `"activeTab"` or `"<all_urls>"` permission does not grant the required rights.

A glance on the Chromium bug tracker did not find an existing feature request for that - you may [try your luck](https://crbug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Xan, it's [a chromium bug](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/919984) that extensions cannot work on data URIs.

A [fix](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/919984) is going in that will rectify this, hopefully landing in Chrome 66.