# Why won't window.location.href work on error pages?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension, and if the user goes to a site that doesn't exist, like thiswebsitedoesnotexist.com, I want the extension to redirect them to another page set specifically by me. I am not talking about sites that give 404 errors. I mean sites whose DNS server address cannot be found, so Google Chrome gives you it's standard error page.

I tried using `window.location.href = *link*`, but that doesn't change the webpage. How can I get around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why won't window.location.href work on error pages?

Because, in fact, you are being shown a document with a `data:` URL for internal error pages, despite the address bar showing the intended address. You can verify that with DevTools by inspecting `window.location` in the error page.

`data:` URLs [are not scriptable by Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051387/chrome-tabs-executescript-into-datauri-tab): no host permission allows to inject content scripts into them.

Therefore, attempts to programmatically inject a content script that changes `window.location.href` (or does `console.log`) will fail due to missing permissions, and [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for content scripts in the manifest won't apply.

> How can I get around this?

You can use `chrome.tabs.update` from the background page to navigate away from the error page.

To detect such an error in a background page, probably the best fit is to use [`chrome.webNavigation` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), though using [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) is also possible (careful with filters, and requires broad permissions). Both will provide `tabId` to do this.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful (more helpful than that stuart guy). I have a second question. I call console.log from the background page, but it doesn't seem to execute! Do you have a solution for this?